# Computer fundamentals about memory

Tags: windows-7

When the capacity of main memory is 2 GB what could be the largest program that can be accessed by the processor with the support of a 32 bits address bus?

Comment: Your wording is rather awkward, but the 32-bit version of Win7 allocates 2GB (of the 4 GB virtual address space) to a user process.   See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2008/11/17/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-virtual-memory/

Answer (score 0):

That would be 2GB in theory, but some of it will be reserved and/or used by the OS itself.

Note that also 32-bit processes are limited to 2GB even if you run them on a 64-bit OS unless intentionally redesigned. If redesigned considering  IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE, the limit becomes, [accoording to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), 3GB.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be 4GB? The amount of main memory doesn't limit program size, and a 32-bit bus can address 4GB. Right?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - The system only has 2 GB of physical memory, a program cannot allocate more then the amount of physical memory accessible to the system. A 32-bit Windows application, would only be able to address 4 GB, if PAE was used.

Comment: @Ramhound A program most certainly can allocate more than the amount of physical memory accessible to the system.

Comment: @David Schwartz swap is a particular case, a specialized secondary type of data storage - not actual memory. It can be used or not. I was referring the the physical memory, not other tricks that can be used to extend its use.

Comment: And then there's the process limit (I have added that in the answer) and the problem of the top bit of pointers that must be zero for an original 32-bit program.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 32 bit adress space then you can address 2^32 (4Gi) bytes of memory. As far as a program running in virtual address space is concerned I see no reason why it could not address and access 4GiB worth.

This assumes a few things, like an OS which uses virtual memory, possibly some hardware (MMU) to assist etc. But for any modern 32 bit CPU and any modern OS this should not be a problem. Everything modern supports paging, so it only has to have the part of that 4GiB that is is currently accessing in physical memory.

So much for a genric answer, now one for windows and x86.

Windows (since win2000 era?) does use virtual memory and paging. It also defaults to splitting the 4Gi address range in half. The top half for the kernel, the lower half for user programs.  That imposes an aritificial limit of 2GiB address for user programs, or 3GiB when you boot the kernel in a special mode and use LARGEADDRESSAWARE programs.

This will limit your USER programs to that.

Then there is PAE, artificaly expanding your memory bus to 36 bits. PAE is an ugly kludge and not needed since 64 bit CPUs (which have been common for the last two decades).

Thi is turning into a 'what-if' then 'answer X' post. Which means it would be nice to have a more specific question.